# Industry best practice for minimizing tracking error

Tags: portfolio-optimization, portfolio-management, factor-models, tracking-error

Lets say I have an alpha generating model that forecasts expected returns for SP500 stocks. I formulate a portfolio with 100 stocks having the highest expected return. What is the simplest way of reducing tracking error relative to the S&P500?

Comment: Pls don't re-ask a closed question even if reworded. Take a look at the "[What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions)" help page if you wish to have your question reopened.

Answer (score 1):

You ask about industry practice. In my experience, generally there are two phases: First an *alpha model* (which it seems you already have) proposes stocks likely to have above average returns, then a *portfolio building model* chooses from these stocks to form a portfolio with characteristcs similar (or not too distant) from the sp500 characteristics (in terms of sector composition, large cap/small cap and other variables considered relevant (in fact *factor models* are often used at this stage to compare the proposed portfolio to the sp500 portfolio and ensure they are no too far apart. For example the S&P500 may have a certain exposure to the oil price factor and you don't want your portfolio to have much more or much less exposure to this factor. Such models are commenrcially available BTW)).